# PHP execute SSH2 command

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm having some problems with PHP SSH2 commands.
So I have succesfully connected my dedicated server with my app, but I have no idea how to run command with that. 
I'm using phpsclib ( http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net ), when I write something like

```
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("ls -la\n");
echo $ssh->read();
```

It will give me a list from root, but the problem is I don't want to be in root.
I need to cd /another_file and execute command that will start some game server.
I tried something like

```
$ssh->write("cd /another_file");
$ssh->write("my command here");
```

But no success, it's showing commands in same line.
Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

- Chain the commands using `$ssh->write()`:

  ```
  $ssh->write("cd /another_file && ls -la\n");
  ```

  ...or...

  ```
  $ssh->write("cd /another_file; ls -la\n");
  ```
- Chain the commands using `$ssh->exec()`. Works much the same way as above except that you don't need to append `\n` to your command and you don't need to bother with the `$ssh->read()`.
- Do multiple `$ssh->write()` calls, which is what your current attempt is attempting to do. But it's doing it wrong:

  ```
  $ssh->write("cd /another_file");
  $ssh->write("my command here");
  ```

  In your first code snippet you're appending a `\n` but you're not doing so on these lines. You need to because, when you're in an interactive shell, the way the shell knows that you're done typing the command out is because you hit the enter button. That's how Linux knows you're done typing and are ready for your command to run.

  You also need to read the prompt before running the next command. eg. `$ssh->read('[prompt]')` or whatever is appropriate for your system. I suppose you could just omit passing a parameter to `$ssh->read()` all together, as you do in your first code snippet, but then it'll take 10s or so for `$ssh->read()` to return any output when it could have alternatively been returning output instantly.